# Pass array into List init

Tags: swift, swiftui

In iOS 16, `List` has a new initializer with the `editActions` parameter, which allows you to use `editActions` together with `EditButton()` instead of applying several modifiers `.onMove, .onDelete`, etc.

```swift
struct QuestionView: View {

    @State
    private var data: [Int] = Array(1...100)

    @State
    private var searchQuery: String = ""

    var filteredData: [Int] {
        switch searchQuery.isEmpty {
        case true: return data
        case false: return data.filter { $0.description.contains(searchQuery) }

        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            // New init take a $data: Binding<[Int]>
            // i can’t pass filteredData: [Int]
            List($data, id: \.self, editActions: .all) {
            // List(filteredData, id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0.wrappedValue)")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Example")
            .searchable(text: $searchQuery)
            .toolbar { EditButton() }
        }
    }
}
```

How to save the search capability (pass `filteredData`) and pass the binging to the new `List` initializer?

Comment: The List initializer will need to be given a binding to some stored state, otherwise what would its edits even do? So `filteredData` would need to be a stored property and not a computed one. However, I see a big issue with that: the edits made will impact the filtered data, but won't be reflected if you reset the search and show all the data (since the changes would have been made to `filteredData` but not the original `data`)

Comment: > filteredData would need to be a stored property and not a computed one

I understand that it shouldn't be computed. You mean something like this:

@State private var selection: DataType?

Comment: Yes. Think of it this way. A `Binding` is a convenient way to package up a getter and setter function. The `List` needs a binding because it needs to be able to call the getter to get the elements it needs to show, but it also needs a setter to know what to do with the edits you make. That setter needs *somewhere* to store the changes being made.

Comment: What do you want to happen if, say, the list is filtered to only show numbers 10 and 100, and the order is changed? Should that be reflected in the original `data`? What positions should they now have?

Comment: According to the idea, the original data should not be affected.
I want to implement delete + change the order when you click the Edit button. If I went into edit mode and deleted an item, when you exit, that item should disappear. If you change the order - the order must remain. I still think it should be in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

```
var filteredData: Binding<[Int]> {
    Binding {
        if searchQuery.isEmpty {
            return data
        }  
        return data.filter { $0.description.contains(searchQuery) }
    } set: { newData in 
        if searchQuery.isEmpty {
            data = newData
        } else {
          // But what do you want to happen here?
        }
    }
}
```

and then…

```
List(filteredData, id: \.self, editActions: .all) {
    Text("\($0.wrappedValue)")
}
```

The question is, what happens when the original data when the filtered data is edited (re-ordered or an item deleted)?

Comment: As in the Notes.app by Apple.
You can add a new Folder, click Edit button and delete or re-order item.